# Differences in some filenames case after uploading to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, filenames, case-sensitive

I uploaded a lot of files (about 5,800) to Amazon S3, which seemed to work perfectly well, but *a few* of them (about 30) had their filenames converted to lowercase.

The first time, I uploaded with [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/). When I saw this problem, I deleted them all and re-uploaded with [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/). Same result.

I see absolutely no pattern that would link the files that got their names changed, it seems very random.

Has anyone had this happen to them?
Any idea what could be going on?

Thank you!
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I let you know first that Amazon S3 object URLs are case sensitive. So when you upload file file with upper case and access that file with same URL, it was working. But after renaming objects in lower case and I hope you are trying same older URL so you may get access denied/NoSuchKey error message.

Can you try [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/be-download.html) to generate the file URL for Amazon S3 object and then try to access that file?

**Disclosure**: I work for Bucket Explorer.

Comment: I've politely asked you in March already: Please take care when promoting your product, see the respective FAQ [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) for details (_If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons_). Also, please refrain from using signatures/taglines, see the respective FAQ [Can I use a signature or tagline?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) for details. You should continue to provide helpful content and the rest will follow ...

Comment: I know they are case sensitive, generating the URL is not my problem. I'm doing a large data import, where I have a bunch of files on my disk, and I take note of their filenames. I later upload everything, and I expect those files to be there, with the correct filename. My problem is that that's not happening. I haven't looked much at your product, but from your description it seems to solve the "generating the URL part", rather than "uploading the files and having them keep the correct filename"

Answer (score 0):

When I upload to Amazon servers, I always use Filezilla and STFP.  I never had such a problem. I'd guess (and honestly, this is just a guess since I haven't used Cyberduck nor Transmit) that the utilities you're using are doing the filename changing.  Try it with Filezilla and see what the result is.

Comment: Are you using Filezilla to connect directly to S3? I don't see that as an option in Filezilla, or SFTP/SSH directly to S3... Do you have an EC2 server in Amazon that is an SFTP server?

Comment: I use Filezilla on EC2 (Linux).  Since SFTP is included in SSH, it works as soon as I open port 22, set up the keypairs, configure Filezilla, and connect.  There's no need to install an SFTP server.